# Show loop content according to value, inside another loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

**Scenario:**

I have a post type `portfolio` and a custom post type `song`, and also a custom taxonomy called `songs_categories`.

Portfolio is inside **loop 1** and the songs are in **loop 2**, which is inside **loop 1**.

What I need to do is to show the songs in the portfolio but only if the songs `category slug` (album name) has the actual value of the portfolios `post_name` (album name).

I can get the values needed but I'm having trouble writing the actual function necessary to do the filtering. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!-- Loop 1 -->

<div class="songs">

<?php 

  $var1 = $post->post_name;  
  $my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=song' );

    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

?>

    <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'songs_categories' ); 
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'songs_categories' );
            if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
            continue;

        echo "$var1";
        echo "$term->slug";

       } ?>

    <div class="col one">

        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>

         h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  

        <?php
        $autor_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_cmb_autor_text", false);
        if ($autor_name[0]=="") { ?>

        <!-- If there are no custom fields, show nothing -->

        <?php } else { ?>

        <?php foreach($autor_name as $autor_name) {
        echo '<p>'.$autor_name.'</p>';
        } ?>

    <?php } ?>  
    </div> 

<?php endwhile; ?>  <!-- End 2nd loop -->
</div> <!-- End songs -->

<?php endif; endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; // password check ?> <!-- End 1st loop -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the desired result by modifying my query:

```
<?php 

$var1 = $post->post_name;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'song',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'songs_categories',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $var1,
        ),

    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just modify your wp_query to include the filters you want

```
$args= array(
    'post_type'=>'song',
    'category_name'=>$post->post_name
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Wp_query is quite detailed you should read up on it to get the most from it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for your input. Went over the codex once more, started from scratch, and  then finally I figured it out.